# Does GAE datastore internally use memcache?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

As you can see from the attached screenshot, the datastore asks memcache to delete an entry inside a put(). What's that?

[image: A screenshot of a write to the datastore]

Comment: what do you use? programming language, database lib, etc?

Comment: What Igor said... both NDB (python) or Objectify (Java) use memcache, that is not datastore behavior though, but the wrapper around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least the ndb datastore caches [include memcache](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/cache#memcache):

The pattern you observed could be explained in this section:

> Memcache does not support transactions. Thus, an update meant to be
>   applied to both the Datastore and memcache might be made to only one
>   of the two. To maintain consistency in such cases (possibly at the
>   expense of performance), the updated entity is deleted from memcache
>   and then written to the Datastore.